# Extracting a specific number from a string

Tags: javascript

I have an element in javascript like follows:

```
var count1 = '<span data-modelName="count[0]"> 3 </span>';
var count2 = '<span data-modelName="count">3</span>';
```

I want to extract 3 from the span element. How can i do it? The content within span element will be any number of digits.

Comment: Create an element to hold the markup, then access the `textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pure javascript:

```
var integer = parseInt(count1.substr(count1.indexOf('>') + 1, count1.indexOf('</') - count1.indexOf('>') - 1));
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4q4t/

Answer (score 1):

It's super easy if you're using jQuery.

```
var selector = $('<span data-modelName="count[0]"> 3 </span>');
var three = selector.html();
```

If you want to have it formatted as an integer (i.e. do math on it), it's one extra step

```
three = parseInt(three);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6RW5/)